# How to get all nodes from instagram response

Tags: javascript, instagram, fetch, instagram-api

I trying to work with Instagram. As I know from 2016 Instagram closed their API. But I found hack.

If I want to get some picture with hashtag I do this.

```
https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/hashtag/?__a=1&max_tag_id=10
```

and get response with json like this

[image]

But if I tried to do this with fetch(JS) I have different numbers of nodes for different hashtags.

My question is. Maybe somebody know how to set number of nodes what I need or how to get all nodes?

My code with JS is bellow

```js
let promises = fetch('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/dog/?__a=1');
promises.then(r => r.json()).then(r => console.log(r))
```

Update.
Add example where nodes are counted

```js
let promise = fetch('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/dog/?__a=1');
    promise.then(r => r.json()).then(response => console.log(response.tag.media.nodes.length));
let promise2 = fetch('https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/cat/?__a=1');
    promise2.then(r => r.json()).then(response => console.log(response.tag.media.nodes.length));
```

Thank you in advance.